# Why can't these variables be resolved?

Tags: java

I need to write a program and, in one step of it, I need to construct a function that calculates the number of rabbits.

The problem is that Eclipse shows a message saying that the variable I created *"cannot be resolved to a variable"* and I don't understand why it happens. Can someone help me?

Here is part of my code

I am showing all my code because it would get bigger and it is not needed, in order to solve this problem

```
class Rabbits {
    static int nbRabbits = initRabbits;        // ERROR HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    static int nbFoxes = initFoxes;           // ERROR HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    int rabbits = 0;

    public static int calculateRabbits(int rabbits, int foxes, double AttackRate) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Duration; ++i) {
            rabbits = nbRabbits;
            nbRabbits *= (1.0 + Rabbits_growth_rate - AttackRate * nbFoxes);
        }
        return nbRabbits;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Enter initial population
        int initFoxes = enterPopulation("foxes", 2, keyb); //at least 2 foxes
        int initRabbits = enterPopulation("rabbits", 5, keyb); //at least 5 rabbits

        // SOME MORE CODE HERE
    }   // end main
} // end of class
```

`initRabbits` and `initFoxes` are variables entered by the user when I call `enterPopulation` method.

I'm new to Java and, unfortunately, I cannot change the logic of this code. For example, I cannot put the `calculateRabbits` method inside the `main` neither change the begin or the end of the code.

Comment: *"nitRabbits and initFoxes are variables entered by the user"* - So, to start with `initRabbits` and `initFoxes` are out of context, they only have meaning within the `main` method.  Second, when `nbRabbits ` and `nbFoxes` are initialised, the values you are (trying) to assign them would have no meaningful value, assuming that they were in scope/context

Comment: `int rabbits = 0.0;` can you explain why you want to initialize an integer number with a double number?

Comment: The more I look at it, the more this hurts my head.  This code is so wrong it's almost impossible to help.  Oh, and hi fellow tom.

Answer (score 0):

`initRabbits` only exists within the main method.  That is it's *scope*.

You are attempting to statically reference something it can't see.  You are attempting to populate nRabbits before a value for innitRabbits exists. This is impossible.

Comment: I understand. So, how can I initialize the `nbRabbits` inside my method `calculateRabbits`, with the values given by the user? As you see in my code , I was trying to do it.

Comment: `calculateRabbits` method

Comment: The short answer is this.  You can't.  Unless you can modify the main method to populate the static nRabbits you're doomed.  What calls your method?  Can you make initRabbits a parameter?

Comment: A `void` method outside the `main` will call my method and I cannot make initRabbits a parameter. The method needs to be exactly like that `public static int calculateRabbits(int rabbits, int foxes, double AttackRate)`

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this I don't know where to start.  You are being passed the number of rabbits as a parameter.  Then you do rabbits = nbRabbits; which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to assign a value to your nb variables from a variable that hasn't been created yet. Skip making four variables and just assign the nbs to 0 outside of your main class, then give them the value you want inside it. They will then retain that value outside of the main class and be visible.

```
static int nbRabbits = 0;
static int nbFoxes = 0;

//in main class
nbFoxes = enterPopulation("foxes", 2, keyb); //at least 2 foxes
nbRabbits = enterPopulation("rabbits", 5, keyb); //at least 5 rabbits
```